# For loop hitting wrong elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm struggling to find out why the for loop below is hitting all tr:nth-child( i<20)..

When I target each tr independently, i.e. $("tr:nth-child(4)")}, the result is correct. Any ideas?

```
for (j=4; j <20; j++) {
  $("tr").insertBefore("tr:nth-child("+j+")");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: Please note: If you don't want to pollute your outer scope you should restrict the scope of `j`: `for(var j=4; ...`

Comment: any chance that by inserting them before, it will only insert the 4th correctly? So, for eg: `1 2 3 4 5` then insert before 2 nr 2 would be `1 2 2 3 4 5` and then 3 before nr 3 would be `1 2 3 2 3 4 5`. Maybe try to reverse your loop logic? (from 19 to 4?)

Answer (score 0):

This loops starts at 4, and incremenets by one. You'll insertbefore on the following indexed elements :

4,5,6,...18,19

Are you sure you want to insertBefore, and do you want this instead

```
for (var j=4; j <=20; j+=4) {
```